# SQL Server 2012 Performance Issue when replicating to New Database

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have moved data from our production database to a new database with all constraints and indexes for load testing.

There is no issue in performance in the original database. When I try to login to the application with the new database connection, all queries take too much time to run even with the indexes.

I have rebuild all the indexes

Am I missing something? Please advise me on this.

I am using SQL Server 2012 for both the databases.

Comment: the next step should be a search of wait events on a new server. it may be a performance issue connected with resources of the environment

Comment: Do you have the same hardware resources assigned to the new database?

Comment: thanks Dale Burrell. thank you for your suggestion. please help me on this.

Comment: I did make a suggestion above. But otherwise there isn't enough information - we'd just be guessing.